# Can I have some help installing python-captcha? dpkg error 1

Tags: python

I have searched around the forums and tried a number of solutions but nothing I have tried has fixed my problem. Here is the terminal info

```
john@ubuntu:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo apt-get install python-captcha
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-captcha
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/384 kB of archives.
After this operation, 516 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 182992 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python-captcha (from .../python-captcha_0.4-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-captcha_0.4-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/pyshared/Captcha/Base.py', which is also in package python-pycaptcha 0.4-1~precise1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-captcha_0.4-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have installed `python-pycaptcha` (maybe from a PPA), which can't be installed at the same time as the system `python-captcha`. See, if this fixes your problem:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pycaptcha python-captcha+
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks. I was told to install pycaptcha and also saw python-captcha, and thought what the hell python-captcha might help as well.